# angular.js routing only on webserver

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) so bear with me. I found Angular's routing pretty neat which is why I want to try my first Webpage with it. My approach is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testrouting</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div id="inject" ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the an `app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'routes/index.html'    
    });
});
```

problem is, that `index.html` is not shown. Inside `index.html` I have a plain `<p>` element with some text. But no text is showing on my root index. As far as I know angular is a front-end framework, so is there any Webserver neccessary which causes the problem?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you have to run it from a webserver otherwise angular can't request your template due to the same-origin policy being enforced for file:// locations.

Comment: Are you saying that you have `/index.html` as a starting point and `/route/index.html` as a partial view?

Comment: just for testing, it works fine so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen places that say that routing requires a server:

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating